# Sequelize keeps throwing the error this[#arrayParserLib].parse is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: this[#arrayParserLib].parse is not a function
    at PostgresQuery.formatError (/Users/vizsatiz/Documents/hub/aesy-api/node_modules/@sequelize/core/src/dialects/postgres/query.js:405:16)
    at PostgresQuery.run (/Users/vizsatiz/Documents/hub/aesy-api/node_modules/@sequelize/core/src/dialects/postgres/query.js:68:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at /Users/vizsatiz/Documents/hub/aesy-api/node_modules/@sequelize/core/src/sequelize.js:732:16
    at Sequelize.queryRaw (/Users/vizsatiz/Documents/hub/aesy-api/node_modules/@sequelize/core/src/sequelize.js:712:12)
    at PostgresQueryInterface.showIndex (/Users/vizsatiz/Documents/hub/aesy-api/node_modules/@sequelize/core/src/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:399:12)
    at Function.sync (/Users/vizsatiz/Documents/hub/aesy-api/node_modules/@sequelize/core/src/model.js:850:29)
    at Sequelize.sync (/Users/vizsatiz/Documents/hub/aesy-api/node_modules/@sequelize/core/src/sequelize.js:828:9)
[ERROR] 20:13:10 SequelizeDatabaseError: this[#arrayParserLib].parse is not a function
```

Happens when I try to connect to postgres:15-alphine. Couldnt find anything in the internet about this. Any help is appreciated.

This happens when I call `sequelize.sync()` or running migration using umzug